# Running a command within a Python os.system tag

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, syntax-error

I am trying to control my lights via a simple discord bot but am running into an issue. I need to run this command and am using discord.py to do it:

```
if message.content.startswith('$Light-Blue'):
    await os.system('coap-client -m put -u "demo" -k "X2CYInVgcFN7i26k" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5706": "4a418a" }] }' "coaps://192.168.110.241:5684/15001/65537"')
    await message.channel.send('Turned changed color 1 Light')
```

The issue I am having is that Python tries to interpret the commands as Python code because of the tags used. So I get a syntax error. How do fix the code so that Python stops treating the commands as code?

This is the error I am getting:

```
File "bot.py", line 25
    await os.system('coap-client -m put -u "demo" -k "X2CYInVgcFN7i26k" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5706": "4a418a" }] }' "coaps://192.168.110.241:5684/15001/65537"')
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you please add the syntax error that you get?

Comment: I added it the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use just `'` inside `'`-delimited string, as `python` get confused. Please consider using `'''`-delimited string which allows you to have `'` inside that is replace

```
await os.system('coap-client -m put -u "demo" -k "X2CYInVgcFN7i26k" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5706": "4a418a" }] }' "coaps://192.168.110.241:5684/15001/65537"')
```

using

```
await os.system('''coap-client -m put -u "demo" -k "X2CYInVgcFN7i26k" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5706": "4a418a" }] }' "coaps://192.168.110.241:5684/15001/65537"''')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will accept it in 3 minutes because stack overflow has a timer